# how can i get html image tag android?

Tags: android, html, image, hyperlink

How can i get Image tag from html String.

I am getting description like this,

```
  <description><![CDATA[<p>23&nbsp;Mar&nbsp;2012</p><a href="http://newsonair.nic.in/news.asp?cat=State&amp;id=ST9197"><p style='FONT-SIZE: 12px; LINE-HEIGHT: 150%' align='justify'> <img style='FLOAT: left; MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px' height='80' width='80' src=http://www.newsonair.nic.in/writereaddata/news_pictures/PICST9197.jpg?0.533424></a><br> The West Bengal Budget for 2012-13 proposes an additional taxation of 200 crore rupees.The budget placed in the State Assembly by the Finance Minister Dr.</p><br clear="all" />]]></description>
```

i want this link alone:

http://www.newsonair.nic.in/writereaddata/news_pictures/PICST9197.jpg

if anyone know give me some idea to do this,

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a million ways to do it, here is one:

```
 String url = htmlString.substring(htmlString.lastIndexOf("http"), htmlString.indexOf("jpg")+3);
```

Ref:

[String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29)

Comment: Sorry double quotes not single quotes.

Comment: @bundell: this not right way as i known for parsing `XML CDATA` tag?